# Why is the health of my angular app hosted in Elastic Beanstalk degrading?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I am trying to deploy an angular app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.Initially the app gets deployed and I am able to access it with both , Putty as well as web browser.However after sometime , say 1 hour the health of the app automatically goes severe. I am also not able to pull any logs.As soon as I try to pull the logs,the dashboard tries to update my environment and the health status transitions to severe.
Can somebody help me?What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using Beanstalk for an angular application? A frontend app can be hosted on S3…

Comment: Can you give more details, is your site just a static one, or you use some server-side technologies/framework?

Comment: No my site is not static,I am using java spring as my backend.